# Using htaccess Files for Pretty URLS - Opencart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

how to write htaccess if my opencart home page is http://www.stico.com.my/index.php?route=product/category&path=20_59 , i want url to be like this
http://www.stico.com.my

My client want page product category set as homepage.
i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess below the existing RewriteRules

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?route=product/category&path=20_59 [L]
```

**Optional, if you want Pretty URLs**

You should be able to use SEO URLs to get pretty URLs for your products.

Admin > System > Settings > Edit YOUR_STORE > Server:
Make sure Use SEO URLs is checked and make sure the htaccess.txt file has been renamed to .htaccess.

Comment: ok, but url still show http://www.stico.com.my/index.php?route=product/category&path=20_59

Comment: Now when you request the homepage you should be presented with the product page. Note that the product page can still be accessed via the full URL, that part didn't change.